# What determines melee damage?

Tags: dragon-age-2

I am playing as a rogue and I enjoy attacking from a distance with my bow. However, sometimes things get up close and personal. As opposed to Origins and Awakening, you can't have two sets of weapons, so I can't easily switch from a ranged weapon to melee weapons. Hawke however doesn't seem to care and goes off melee attacking foes when they get too close.

So how is that melee damage, while a bow is equipped, determined? Is it only Dexterity with no other modifier? Does the ranged weapon somehow affect the melee damage? Is it worth changing to daggers when things get too hot, or is the difference usually negligible?

Comment: I haven't looked too closely, but I think the "damage per second" rating of the weapon applies the same for both types of attacks. My Hawke is a mage, but also switches to melee when enemies are close enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [dragonage wikia](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_mechanics_%28Dragon_Age_II%29) this is the damage calculation process:

```
 Base Weapon Damage (in the weapon description, not including on-hit bonuses)
 + Primary Attribute Modifier (0.5 per point over 10)
 * Ability Damage Factor (Winter's Grasp is 4.48833 for example)
 * Hit Result Modifier (1.0 for normal hits, 1.5+ for critical hits)
 + Berserk Bonus Damage
 * Damage Type Modifier (stuff like +15% fire damage)
 * Blood Frenzy/Veneer of Calm Modifier (1.0-2.0)
 * Cross class Combo Multiplier (if applicable)
```

That's after a hit has been registered.  Whether you hit or not appears to depend solely on abilities, not range:

```
StatLevel = (Attribute - 10) / ScalingCoefficient
StatValue1 = PropertyData(INTEGER_PART(StatLevel))
StatValue2 = PropertyData(INTEGER_PART(StatLevel) + 1)
StatValue = StatValue1 + FRACTIONAL_PART(StatLevel) x (StatValue2 - StatValue1)
```

And the attribute for rogue is dex.  Scaling coefficient is 1.0 for defense, 1.25 for attack.

Comment: Right, but that would be for the bow equipped on a ranged rogue, or a staff for a mage, both of which magically switch to daggers in close quarters. Does that close quarters damage work the same as long range?

Comment: I see nothing that indicates range has anything to do with the computations.

Comment: What I mean is that it's taking the stats for the bow, but you don't use the bow in close quarters. Does the melee damage use the bow stats?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the bow in close quarters, it deals bow damage.  It's based on class and weapon type and weapon level and attribute.  That's it, excepting other bonus damage properties like fire berserk etc.

If you are asking what happens when you switch to twin dagggers, you then switch two weapon damage.

This chart may help: [chart - click me](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons_%28Dragon_Age_II%29#Weapon_types).

Comment: Bring a snapshot of the chart over, that dual-weapon rogue is likely what the person is looking for. Good find!